# Tabulator getElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I currently have a tabulator table of 100 elements in the array. When I call the function to grab the specific cell, it manages to grab the first 25 rows and change the color of the specific cell that I want.

The problem is that the ones after isn't changing color when everything else is the same. How do I get around it?

Here is the code that I am using to generate the background color. It works for the first 25 rows but it wasn't able to grab the next 75 rows

```
var allRowData = table.getRows();

    // loops the entire row
    allRowData.forEach(x => {

        // using the row data, grab the columns and compare with a condition
        scope.columns.forEach(y => {

            if (y.priority == 3) { // checks for the priority number to add a color to it
                var rowCell = x.getCell(`${y.fieldName}`);
                rowCell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What Tabulator version?  When/where do you see error 'getElement is not a function`? Are all the rows visible?

Comment: Can you set up a Fiddle that replicates this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be trying to directly manipulate the layout of the table from outside of Tabulator.

Tabulator uses a virtual DOM which means that it will create and destroy elements of the table as needed, which means that you can only style elements that are currently visible, when these elements are updated any previous formatting can be lost without notice.

If you wish to style cell elements you must use the `formatter` function in the column definition or the `rowFormatter` function on the table which are called when the rows/cells are redrawn.

Full details of these can be found in the [Formatter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format)

If you are wanting to change the state of rows based on something outside of the table, then your formatters should reference this external variable and when you update the external state you should trigger the `redraw` function on the table to retrigger the formatters